# How can I look at CPU utilization of a particular process across multiple CPUs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu

I am trying to figure out (on Kinux) how to look at a single process and its CPU utilization on individual CPUs.

In particular, I have an app server process running and I want to see how much of each CPU it's using (not just an overall CPU usage across all the CPUs).

I'm thinking of something along the lines of `top`/`htop`/`mpstat`/`sar` but limiting it to a single process and and reporting CPU usage on each processor core.

FWIW, since `top` and `htop` can show individual CPU usage charts, I tried to use each of them to do this.  I tried starting the process as a separate user and then running `htop` as that new user.  In `top`, I tried `-p pid`.  In both `top` and `htop`, the CPU usage charts up top seem to be for the overall system, not just filtered according to the user or process filter that the command was started with (that seems to only matter for the process/thread list).

Comment: Why would you do this?